# Angular 9 - Duplicate column definition name provided - detailExpand

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I have a Problem that did not occur in Angular 8 and previous.

With Angular 9 It seems that If I have Table (master) with an expandable container that has another table (child), angular considers the all the child tables as the same. And thinks that the column of the child is duplicated.

This error won't happen if there is only 1 child table.

I replicated this in
[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-table-dubplicate-col-definition)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I guess that what I had to do, and ultimately is a best practice, is Separate the Child Table into its own component making my template cleaner and more readable.

And that did it.

I don't know if this was a bug for Angular, or it was intentional, but helped at making better code.

Comment: Encountered the same issue, moving the nested table into a different component solved it for me as well.